# Selenium Java : Dropdown items are updated dynamically

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Any inputs will be appreciated:
The web application i am working on does not have the "select" tag, and the items in the drop down get updated dynamically. Meaning when i click on the down arrow of the dropdown menu, it would show about 10 items and when i scrolldown the "scrollbar of the dropdown" more items are populated.
While i can select an item by typing in the value in the "field" of the dropdown box and by then clicking on the "runtime" created xpath Eg. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@text()='USA']).click` which works fine for selecting any item, I would need to get all the items in that drop down.
Is there a way this can be achieved ?

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML or share link?

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: If you didn't deny my reasonable edit, I would keep the vote up for the question.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElement(By by)` and `driver.findElements(By by)` scopes the while DOM.

you can target a small area of the DOM with:
`element.findElement(By by)` and `element.findElements(By by)`

Using this:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.DROPDOWN LOCATOR);
List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.OPTION LOCATOR);
```

You still need the OPTION LOCATOR. But it is easier to achieve, it will collect child elements from the parent element only.

Select methods would look like this:

```
public void selectByText(List<EebElement> options, String text) {
    for (WebElement element: options) {
        if (element.getText().equals(text)) {
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void selectByValue(List<EebElement> options, String value) {
    for (WebElement element: options) {
        if (element.getAttribute("value").equals(value)) {
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```