# how to select a value from dynamic searchbox in selenium webdriver java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoOS1.png)

I have to select a name from this searchbox based on my input value. How I can achieve this.

Comment: Post it's html code and your attempts. Right click -> Inspect -> Copy.

Comment: <input lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" id="input-597" type="text" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Accounts..." maxlength="255" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="dropdown-element-597" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" aria-controls="dropdown-element-597" data-position-id="lgcp-1000025" aria-describedby="help-message-596">

Comment: Can you also do the same with the first element. Aka Gary Chong.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

If html tag for Account name is `<select>...</select>`, you can use `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`

See https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html

**Option 2:**

Use relationship parent-child of elements.

See [Selenium Java : Dropdown items are updated dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507887/selenium-java-dropdown-items-are-updated-dynamically)

and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/locating-child-nodes-of-webelements-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

```
#send something to the input
input=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@role='combobox']") #xpath to input box
input.send_keys("something")

#find the drop down element and scroll to that element
options = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpathtotheoptiondropdown")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", option)

#click that element
option.click()
```