# Select Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select, select-options

I am creating a selenium test with java. I want to automize a dropdown menu in a dialogue.
The xpath of the dropdown menu is:

```
/html/body/div[8]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/select
```

My problem is that I cant select an element from the dropdown menu.
I used:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until
```

and ExpectedCondition to select an element. Can you help me to find a way to select an element from the drop-down.

Comment: Could you also provide the (html) definition of the element?

Comment: Please share url here to check

Comment: dont use absolute path to pick elements in selenium

Comment: I cant share the code or an url, because it is  a secret enterprise application

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65714687/how-to-select-a-value-from-dynamic-searchbox-in-selenium-webdriver-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select one of the [select-options](/questions/tagged/select-options) from a [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *id* and `selectByIndex()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("selectID")))).selectByIndex(1);
  ```
- Using *cssSelector* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("selectCssSelector")))).selectByVisibleText("OptionText");
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `selectByValue()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("selectXpath")))).selectByValue("OptionValue");
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to select an option from a dropdown through Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772710/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-through-selenium-webdriver/49777340#49777340)
- [Trying to select an option from the dropdown in Selenium web automation -error- "ElementNotInteractableException: could not be scrolled into view"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854405/trying-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-in-selenium-web-automation-error/63855001#63855001)
- [How to retrieve the value of options from a select drop-down using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684736/how-to-retrieve-the-value-of-options-from-a-select-drop-down-using-selenium/56685051#56685051)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first click the dropdown button and then find the the button you want to select from the dropdown and then click on it.